# How to remove plain text from a string after using strip_tags()

Tags: php, regex, strip-tags

So i have a string and I used the `strip_tags()` function to remove all tags except IMG but I still have plain text next to my IMG element. Here a visual example

```
$myvariable = "This text needs to be removed<a href='blah_blah_blah'>Blah</a><img src='blah.jpg'>"
```

So using PHP `strip_tags()` I was able to remove all tags except the `<img>` tag (which is what I want). But the thing is now it didn't remove the text.

How do I remove the left over text? Text will always either before tag or after tag as well

**[ADDED MORE DETAILS]**

```
$description = 'crazy stuff<a href="https://websta.me/p/1337373806024694030_327078936"><img src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e15/14287934_1389514537744146_673363238_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMzNzM3MzgwNjAyNDY5NDAzMA%3D%3D.2"></a>';
```

that's what the variable is actually holding.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: a regular expression .. but need to know more about the possible strings

Comment: check out the variable I just added. Thanks In advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of replacing something you can very well extract the values you want:

```
(<(\w+).+</\2>)
```

To be used with `preg_match()`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/mO9gM6/1).
IN `PHP`:

```
<?php
$regex = '~(<(\w+).+</\2>)~';
$string = 'crazy stuff<a href="https://websta.me/p/1337373806024694030_327078936"><img src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e15/14287934_1389514537744146_673363238_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMzNzM3MzgwNjAyNDY5NDAzMA%3D%3D.2"></a>here as well';

if (preg_match($regex, $string, $match)) {
    echo $match[1];
}
?>
```

Comment: What if I just want the img tag portion?

Comment: Then you could use a parser or [**`(<img[^>]+>)`**](https://regex101.com/r/mO9gM6/2)

Answer (score 0):

Please show your whole piece of code with the use of `strip_tags`.

You can try: `preg_replace('~.*(<img[^>]+>)~', '$1', $myvariable);`

Comment: check out the variable I just added. Thanks In advance

Comment: If you use the preg_replace above you will only keep the img tag, isnt it what you want?